# Inconsistent cluster state when creating column families programatically in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, hector

I'm facing $subject, when trying to create column families dynamically. I'm using Hector to do this, and have the default consistency level. I believe, the reason is that Hector returns the create column family method before the column family is replicated across the cluster. How do I handle this in a proper manner?

Answer (score 1):

You believe? Please read this [link](https://github.com/zznate/hector-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/riptano/cassandra/hector/example/SchemaManipulation.java), it has example on how to create the column family and then print out the column family definition. After column family is created in the cassandra cluster, the schema will propagate across the nodes in the cluster. If you want to inspect the column family in cassandra node, you can probably use `cassandra-cli` and command `show schema`.

**Edit:** 
From follow up the comments, the solution is to upgrade the hector to the latest version and call the method `addColumnFamily(cfdef, true);` , that is to wait until the schema is propagated in the cluster. Then start insert data (column name and its value) to this column family.

Comment: When I say programatically, I was looking at doing this from the code. I don't want to use the cli. That link you pointed out does not solve the problem. It's adding a keyspace with a CF. I want to just add a CF (without dropping my keyspace, and losing all the data I have) dynamically, and make sure that it is propagated. I hope I'm making sense here.

Comment: @TharinduMathew I'm sorry as I cannot express myself clearly ;-). Before I do this edit, can I get your confirmation that what exactly are you trying to do. Do you mean you want to dynamically add a column name and its value into the existing column family and verify that the column that is inserted propagated across the cluster?

Comment: Trying again :). 3 node cluster of Cassandra 0.7. I have a concurrency problem. A different number of threads try to create a column family and insert data. So I synchronize this so that only one thread will create a column family, and verify that the change has propagated through the cluster. But this result is inconsistent with Hector. I have partly found a solution. Now I use the Thrift API of describe_schema to check for inconsistent versions across the cluster. But sometimes, it just does not propagate across the cluster and results in 2 schema versions. Any way to approach this?

Comment: How about wait for the schema agreement from the cluster itself? When you add a column family using hector, you call the method `addColumnFamily(cfdef, true);` , that is to wait until the schema is propagated in the cluster. Then you can start insert data (column name and its value) to this column family.

Comment: Thanks Jasonw. I'm using hector 0.7 that doesn't have the overloaded method. But, I took a look at the trunk code, and it does exactly what I have done using the Thrift API. Thanks again, this confirmed my fix is right :)

Comment: I think you should really upgrade hector to the latest version. It should be done by the hector code though.

Comment: I will do it soon. I still noticed that the cluster goes out of sync sometimes, and does not recover even if we wait. I really think this should be fixed from the Cassandra side. There's a workaround to stop the server delete schema files and start again. But that's just too much for a simple problem, don't you think?

Comment: Your question here is about hector and not cassandra. Well questions are good in general but if we do not have specific questions, you can draw from endless topic A to Z. ;-) I do **not** want to guess what happen in your cassandra cluster but using cassandra-cli, it has a command `describe cluster` which will list the schema versions. With that, I think you can verify if the schema are all in sync in the cluster.